# How to develope custom aspx page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

i have a special question i really want to learn how to develop custom aspx page forexample; if you create a aspx page automatically page created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test.xyz
{
    public partial class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }
}
```

But i want to develop: like that if a press create aspx page :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MyFrameWork.Business;
sing MyFrameWork.DAL;
namespace Test.xyz
{
    public partial class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }

   protected void Save()
{

}

   protected void Delete()
{

}
}
```

Howw to generate this page right click - Add new Item (Automatically)

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: I think (I think!) OP wants to customize Visual Studio so as when a new page is created, it looks like his example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a new item template. This page describes what you need:

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx)

(Basically you create your page, then goto File>Export Template and follow the wizard.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to edit Visual Studio's default template for ASPX code-behind files.

You ca n find it in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033`